# EntityQuery group by clause

Tags: entities, 8

Using the EntityQuery API I am trying to add a group by clause to the query, however, it doesn't seem that one exists.  The EntityQuery API does not have a groupBy() method.

Current Code:

```
$nodes = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'thing')
    ->condition('field_num_1', 'value', '=')
    ->condition('field_num_2', 'value', '=')
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->sort('title', 'ASC')
    ->execute();
```

Ideal Code:

```
$nodes = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'thing')
    ->condition('field_num_1', 'value', '=')
    ->condition('field_num_2', 'value', '=')
    ->groupBy('field_num_3')
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->sort('title', 'ASC')
    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For aggregate queries, you need to use the separate method, from https://www.drupal.org/node/1918702:

```
$query = Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('node');

$result = $query
  ->groupBy('type')
  ->aggregate('nid', 'COUNT')
  ->execute();
```

groupBY() alone doesn't do anything. The normal entity query returns entity ID's. Always. It makes no sense to group by a field or anything else. Only in combination with aggregate.

Comment: Actually...I take that back, I think its working.  Awesome!  Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to sort the aggregate results by a field within an entity of one of the results.  So example:  Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('node')->groupBy('field_custom_name')->aggregate('nid', 'COUNT')->sortAggregate('field_custom_another_name', 'SUM', 'DESC')->execute();

Comment: The statement "groupBy() alone doesn't do anything" is incorrect, it returns the values of the grouped column. However, most of the time this is not the result you want so you need to use the aggregate function as well.

Comment: Any way to return the nid list grouping by nid with a order? I mean, something like:
`
      $entityIds = \Drupal::entityQueryAggregate('transaction')
        ->condition('order_date', $from->getTimestamp(), '>')
        ->groupBy('nid')
        ->get the highest node ordering by order_date
        ->execute();
`
I don't want to count or something, only I want to get all transactions nid with a condition and, if any nid are in two rows, get the highest (or really, whatever!).

Comment: @estoyausente that does not sound like a nn aggregate query to me, just a normal query with a sort and range(0, 1).

Comment: Yes, it was the solution that I found :) Thanks Berdir!

Comment: but how do you get the node ids contained on that one? i can see nid_count 2 but how do i know?